# HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://***/date=2020-05-28/hour=20/part-00000-.c000.snappy.parquet (offset=0, length=22009):

Tags: aws-lambda, parquet, amazon-athena, snappy

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # created query
    query = "SELECT * FROM %s.%s limit 50;" % (DATABASE, TABLE)

    # athena client
    client = boto3.client('athena')

    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': S3_OUTPUT,
        }
    )

    # get query execution id
    query_execution_id = response['QueryExecutionId']
    print(query_execution_id)

    # get execution status
    for i in range(1, 1 + RETRY_COUNT):

        # get query execution
        query_status = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
        query_execution_status = query_status['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']

        if query_execution_status == 'SUCCEEDED':
            print("STATUS:" + query_execution_status)
            break

        if query_execution_status == 'FAILED':
            raise Exception("STATUS:" + query_execution_status)
        else:
            print("STATUS:" + query_execution_status)
            time.sleep(100)
    else:
        client.stop_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
        raise Exception('TIME OVER')

    # get query results
    result = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
    print(result)

    # get data
    if len(result['ResultSet']['Rows']) == 2:

        email = result['ResultSet']['Rows'][1]['Data'][1]['VarCharValue']

        return email

    else:
        return None
```

Error message:

> HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://*************/******/date=2020-05-28/hour=20/part-00000-af4a5ab5-d8f9-4868-a974-90b3c2433366.c000.snappy.parquet (offset=0, length=22009):

1. The above error is showing up which I have no idea what's going on. Tried to scan through some other resources but no luck in finding them.
2. I am trying to run the aws lambda function that reads the snappy.parquet data and writes the results to S3.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code, it is helpful to see the effort that you did. Since we don't have access to your environment and can't replicate the error, you need to try and "divide and conquer" the problem. Can you run the query in Athena directly (not in Lambda)? Can you run other Athena queries from your Lambda configuration (IAM roles or AWS regions)?